# How can I record Zoom video and audio, not through Zoom?

Tags: audio, video, video-capture, capture

Suppose I am conducting a Zoom session with audio and video; and that session is configured so that Zoom itself is not recording. But - I still want to record/capture the video and the audio of the session, not through Zoom itself.

Is this possible? If so, can it be done at some higher-level, as opposed to fully-uncompressed video and audio data?

The operating system is Windows 7 Pro SP1. If hardware specs are necessary, I'll provide them.

Comment: Why not configure the zoom session accordingly? -- Also: Windows 7??

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: 1. Because sometime Zoom requires speaker permission for recording, and you might not want to ask for it. 2. It's not my computer, I don't use Windows. But - what's the matter with Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

You could record in video the screen area of Zoom.

A well-recommended free product is [ShareX](https://getsharex.com/),
but there are
[others](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-screen-session-recorder.htm).

I am unsure how well these products will capture the speaker and the microphone
together, so you will need to study these products to find that out.

Comment: I'll try those, but a quick Googling with some alternative phrases found a trial-ware which worked, so I know that this works in principle.